# Convert text box output to be enclosed in single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, jqplot

When giving string input from a text box to a key  of Json variable, In firebug, I am finding that the value is being enclosed by double quotes. Can I avoid this and make that my string to be surrounded by single quotes?

I got this need while using 
[jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com), which is used for rendering graphs. In configuring jqpot options, some of the values like options.axesDefaults.tickOptions.mark , etc in  [jqplot options](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) require values to be enclosed in single quotes. I need to set these options according to user input.

Can any one please provide me solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the quotes make no difference whatsoever if your library is written in JavaScript. What makes you think this requirement exists?

Comment: Sorry for my post, It seems like it is due to another mistake in my code. It is not related to type of quotes. Sorry all again, for my stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Single quote delimited strings are not valid JSON. It looks like you have a JavaScript object, which isn't JSON.

In JavaScript, there is no difference between single and double quotes.

The example you linked doesn't *require* single quotes, it just has them there in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var someVal = "\"test\""
// Global search for " and replace with ' in supplied string
var quoteReplacedVal = someVal.replace(/\"/g,"'");
```